# Xfce4 autologin lightdm

Tags: xfce, auto-login, xfce4, autologon, lightdm

How do I configure autologin for xfce4? I tried setting aurologin groups but those don't work, there is nothing in the startup section of settings and no apt pkg as far as I'm aware.